# Django sort_by and distinct

Tags: django

I am having trouble doing this:

```
MY_MODEL.objects.order_by('foo').distinct('bar')
```

I am using Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I just used python's built-in sorted() function.

```
x = MY_MODEL.objects.distinct('bar')
result = sorted(x, key=lambda my_model: my_model.foo)
```

Personally, I think this is a bug in Django. Sure, the SQL might not work out, but Django should abstract that away.